# parsing a string in SAS 9.2 that contains the '|' character

Tags: regex, sas

I have a variable that contains a number of firms separated by the | symbol.  I would like to be able to count how many firms there. i.e., the number of | + 1, and ideally identify the location of the | symbol in the string.  Note there will not be more than five firms in a single variable.  I was trying to use the following approach but run into the fact that SAS treats the | symbol as a special operator.

```
pattern1 = prxparse('/|/'); /* I can't seem to get SAS to treat this as a text to compare */
start = 1;
stop = length(reassignment2); /* my list of firms is in the variable reassignment2 */
call prxnext(pattern1, start, stop, reassignment2, position, length);
ARRAY Y[5];
do J=1 to 5 while (position > 0);

  Y[J]=position;
  call prxnext(pattern1, start, stop, reassignment2, position, length);
end;
nfirms=j+1;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it somewhat differently.  What you really want is not the number of | characters, but the actual firms, right? So search for those.  Your code had a number of minor issues; primarily, you must first `prxmatch` before using `call prxnext`, your j+1 is wrong because the loop iterator actually increments one beyond the last qualifying loop value (I use j-1 because I will find one more element than you), and `|` is a regular expression metacharacter and must be escaped if you actually want to use it, unless it is inside `[]` like I am using it.

```
data test;
infile datalines truncover;
input @1 reassignment2 $50.;
pattern1 = prxparse('/[^|]+/io'); /* Look for non-| characters */
start = 1;
stop = length(reassignment2); /* my list of firms is in the variable reassignment2 */
rc=prxmatch(pattern1,reassignment2);
if rc>0 then do;
    ARRAY Y[5];
    do J=1 by 1 until (position = 0);
      call prxnext(pattern1, start, stop, reassignment2, position, length);
      Y[J]=position;
    end;
    nfirms=j-1;
end;
else nfirms=0;
put nfirms=;
datalines;
Firm1|Firm2|Firm3
Firm1|Firm2|Firm3|Firm4
Firm1
Firm1|Firm2
;;;;
run;
```

For completeness' sake, you could also do this easily without regular expressions, using `call scan`.

```
data test;
infile datalines truncover;
input @1 reassignment2 $50.;
array y[5];
do nfirms=1 by 1 until (position le 0);
    call scan(reassignment2,nfirms,position,length,'|');
    y[nfirms]=position;
end;
nfirms=nfirms-1; *loop ends one iteration too late;
put nfirms=;
datalines;
Firm1|Firm2|Firm3
Firm1|Firm2|Firm3|Firm4
Firm1
Firm1|Firm2
;;;;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Joe that this could be done more simply without regular expressions, though I would simplify his code a little further to exclude the use of an array.

```
data test;
    infile datalines truncover length = reclen;
    input firmlist $varying256. reclen;
    i = 0;
    do until(scan(firmlist,i,"|") = "");
        i + 1;
    end;
    nfirms = i - 1;
    drop i;
    datalines;
Firm1|Firm2|Firm3
Firm1|Firm2|Firm3|Firm4
Firm1
Firm1|Firm2
;
run;
```

You said you'd also like to capture the position of the "|" character in the string, but if there are multiple firms per record there will be multiple "|" characters in the string. If you want the position of each one, an array might be a better route, though if you only want one, the `index` function will get you what you want. You'd use `delimpos = index(firmlist,"|");`.

I hope that helps!

Comment: The array is to store the position of each record; the OP stated this as a desired output.

Comment: OP: I would go with @Joe's answer if I were you. :)